# Updating chart.js bar graph in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using `Chart.js` to create a simple bar chart with only two rows and 2 sets of data. I am new to using the library and after reading the examples, I feel comfortable with most of the things there. Here is what I have so far

**JS code for graph:**

```
var helpers = Chart.helpers;
var canvas = document.getElementById('bar');


var barChartData = {
    labels: ["IBM", "Microsoft"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Product A",
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",

      data: [25, 75]
    }, {
      label: "Product B",
      fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",

      data: [75, 25]
    }]

  }
  // 
var bar = new Chart(canvas.getContext('2d')).Bar(barChartData, {
  tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>kb",
  animation: false,
})

;
```

Now, I was wondering if it is possible to update this graph if the data was changed in real time without refreshing the page. For instance if every second the data values keep swapping or something random happens the graph should reflect the changes. I have searched a lot but not found proper document or tutorial explaining this and I would highly appreciate it if someone can show me how to do this.

This is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z10n2vty/) I have created for work so far.

Comment: Search for .update() in Chart.js docs, and here is the example for updating the chart. [Sample Code](http://jsfiddle.net/z10n2vty/1/)

Comment: @user1010101 - are you looking at updating barChartData and have the updated values reflect in the chart (or do the Aprian's comment and Anand's answer solve your problem)

Comment: @yes accepted answer that is what i was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use the method `addData()`, Example:

```
bar.addData([40, 60], "Google");
```

Working example - http://jsbin.com/kalilayohu/1/

Comment: Is there a way to then remove the first data point (and it's label) from the graph at the same time? To give it a more long-term real-time feel.

Answer (score 4):

this is the code

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas,{
data:{
labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset", 
        data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],


           borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
},
    options:{
    scales: {
    yAxes:[{
        stacked:true,
        gridLines: {
        display:true,
        color:"rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
        }
    }],
    xAxes:[{
            gridLines: {
            display:false
         }
       }]
    }
  }
 });
```

**You can update doing this:**

```
myBarChart.data.datasets[0].data[4] = 50;//this update the value of may
myBarChart.update();
```